# How do I use Maximum for a SELECT statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I have to create a query to fulfill this question: What is the maximum number of tickets that a single customer bought in one day? Your results should have 3 columns ( HippCode, Date of Purchase, and the number of tickets) and just 1 row in the results.

Comment: Is it your homework?

Comment: You don't have any client_id in your tables. Anyway, you just need to add GROUP BY 'date' \ 'client_id' for grouping and SELECT SUM() \ MAX() depends on your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Is HippCode the personid?

```
select HippCode, DateBought as 'Date of Purchase', count(*) as 'Number of Tickets'
from ticket
group by HippCode, DateBought
order by count(*) desc
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Select max(effort) from others where homework = 'mine'